# Spring Boot profile. How to test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, spring-boot

How can I test my profiles?

that's my test

```
    @Test
public void testDevProfile() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    Application.main(new String[0]);
    String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
    Assert.assertTrue(output.contains("The following profiles are active: dev"));
}

@Test
public void testUatProfile() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "uat");
    Application.main(new String[0]);
    String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
    Assert.assertTrue(output.contains("The following profiles are active: uat"));
}

@Test
public void testPrdProfile() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "prd");
    Application.main(new String[0]);
    String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
    Assert.assertFalse(output.contains("The following profiles are active: uat"));
    Assert.assertFalse(output.contains("The following profiles are active: dev"));
    Assert.assertFalse(output.contains("The following profiles are active: default"));
}
```

My first test executes OK but the others fail.

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.DataEndpointMBean@6cbe68e9] with key 'requestMappingEndpoint'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=requestMappingEndpoint
```

How can I stop the instance before the next test start? Or which is the better approach?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootApp.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ProfileDevTest {

    @Value("${someProperty}")
    private String someProperty;

    @Test
    public void testProperty() {
        assertEquals("dev-value", someProperty);
    }
}
```

The code above assumes you have an `application-dev.properties` like this:

```
someProperty=dev-value
```

I would have one test **class** per profile you wish to test, this one above is for profile **dev**. If you **must** have a test on the active profiles (rather than a property), you may do this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Test
public void testActiveProfiles() {
    assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"dev"}, environment.getActiveProfiles());        
}
```